# Django choosing which model to use in Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

[image]I have three models

models.py

```
class Cluster(models.Model):
    blockOption= (('IMG', 'IMG'),('DESC', 'DESC'),)
    block = models.CharField(max_length= 100, choices=blockOption)
    order= models.IntegerField(null=True)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, verbose_name=('Link to Post'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        
class Image(models.Model):
    src = models.ImageField(verbose_name=('Imagefile'))
    captions= models.CharField(max_length= 100, null=True)
    cluster = models.ForeignKey(Cluster, verbose_name=('Link to Post'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Description(models.Model):
    text=models.TextField(max_length=400)
    cluster = models.ForeignKey(Cluster, verbose_name=('Link to Post'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and in admin.py

```
class ImageAdminInline(TabularInline):
    extra = 1
    model = Image
class DescriptionAdminInline(TabularInline):
    model= Description

@admin.register(Cluster)
class ClusterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines= (ImageAdminInline, DescriptionAdminInline)
```

I have put ImageAdminInline and DescriptionAdminInline as inlines to ClusterAdmin.
I' m planning to use ClusterAdmin to choose which admin I would be using. I hope it will be something similar to wagtail's streamfield(image above).
Is there any solution that I could use without overriding admin template?

I have tried using Ajax to just hide or show inlines but it was my first time to override django's template so it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two separate admin classes, one for Image and one for Description, and then use the block field in the Cluster model to determine which admin class to use in the Django admin. Here's an example:

```
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

@admin.register(Description)
class DescriptionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

@admin.register(Cluster)
class ClusterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_model_admin(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj and obj.block == "IMG":
            return ImageAdmin
        elif obj and obj.block == "DESC":
            return DescriptionAdmin
        else:
            return super().get_model_admin(request, obj)
    
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        model_admin = self.get_model_admin(request, obj)
        if model_admin:
            form.base_fields.update(model_admin.get_form(request, obj, **kwargs).base_fields)
        return form
```

This will use the ClusterAdmin as the main admin class for the Cluster model, but it will dynamically use either the ImageAdmin or DescriptionAdmin to display the appropriate fields based on the value of the block field in the Cluster model.

Comment: hey thanks for your soulution. I get the idea but as I tried your code there 's an error saying `'super' object has no attribute 'get_model_admin'` I'm not really sure what's missing here.